# Obtain fairly sampled data set subject to a condition?

Tags: random, conditional, findinstance

I need to obtain a random distribution of some parameters `{t1,t2,t3}` subject to a set of conditions. For example,

`{(t1,t2,t3)| p1(t1,t2,t3)>0, p2(t1,t2,t3)==0}`

So far, my only idea has been to use `FindInstance` in the following way:

`tpoints = {t1,t2,t3}/.FindInstance[p1(t1,t2,t3)>0&&p2(t1,t2,t3)==0,{t1,t2,t3},numpoints`

where `numpoints` is the size of the sample that I want. However, It's unclear to me how `FindInstance` works and whether constructing a data set this way is truly a "good" (random) data set.

Update: I should also mention that until the conditions are imposed, the parameters (t1, t2, t3) can be any real numbers. Additionally, the conditions p1, p2, etc. are linear and quadratic polynomial constraints.

Comment: You could try something like `RandomPoint @ ImplicitRegion[conditions, parameters]`.

Comment: Until you specify the (unconditional) joint distribution of $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ (which includes the range of values the parameters can take: integers? non-negative reals?) and the definitions of `p1` and `p2`, I don't think there's much specific advice one can give.  The general advice should help but might not capitalize on efficiencies knowing more information.

Comment: @JimB thanks, just updated the post with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the term "fairly sampled data set" is well defined.

Given the two types of constraints (an inequality and an equality), you'll likely need to solve explicitly for the equality (`p2`), generate samples from a known multivariate distribution, and then `Select` the subset that satisfies the inequality (`p1`).

Suppose `p2 = t1^2 + t2^2 - t3^2` is the equality.  Then we can solve for `t3` as follows:

```
p2 = t1^2 + t2^2 - t3^2;
Solve[p2 == 0, t3]
(* {{t3 -> -Sqrt[t1^2 + t2^2]}, {t3 -> Sqrt[t1^2 + t2^2]}} *)
```

We'll assume that `t3` could take either value equally likely.  Also let

```
p1 = Total[{t1, t2, t3}]
```

Now generate the restricted samples:

```
n = 10000;  (* Maximum sample size *)

(* Generate random sample of (t1, t2) from a bivariate normal \
distribution *)
ρ = 0;
t12 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, ρ], n];

(* Add in the value of t3 determined by the equality *)
t3 = (Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] & /@ 
     t12)*(2*RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1/2], n] - 1);
t123 = Join[t12, Transpose[{t3}], 2];

(* Select the samples that satisfy p1 (the inequality constraint) *)
sample = Select[t123, Total[#] > 0 &];

(* Show the results *)
GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[Text[Style["ρ = 0", Bold, Italic, 36]]],
   ListPlot[sample[[All, {1, 2}]], AxesLabel -> {"t1", "t2"}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> 1]},
  {ListPlot[sample[[All, {1, 3}]], AxesLabel -> {"t1", "t3"}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> 1],
   ListPlot[sample[[All, {2, 3}]], AxesLabel -> {"t2", "t3"}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> 1]}}]
```

[image: Restricted sampling of t1, t2, and t3 with rho = 0]

But now use $\rho=0.9$:

[image: Restricted sampling of t1, t2, and t3 with rho = 0.9]

Different values of ρ result in wildly different samples as does the choice of the joint distribution.

So setting the restrictions is just part of what needs to be specified.  You also need to specify the joint distribution of `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`.  (With the example I used you just need to specify the joint distribution of `t1` and `t2` because one can solve for `t3` in terms of `t1` and `t2`.)